# phpmyadmin export database gives html document error with name sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I am exporting database from phpmyadmin it gives me .sql html document. I have tried from both custom and quick export and I have also used from chrome and mozilla browser. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please help. I have waste whole night on this. May be its a system problem or browser promblem because I have tried to export database from phpmyadmin which is in my local machine and also from server both is giving same problem. the document like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang='en' dir='ltr' class='firefox firefox39'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <style id="cfs-style">html{display: none;}</style>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css?v=4.5.2" />
    <link .........
```

Comment: Is your database large? Can you try a test export from the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Comment: I suppose you might be exceeding some webserver resource limit; can you also look in your webserver error log to see if there are any hints there?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs by due to very large size of database.

Go to your bin folder (if you are on local server) and type:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root -p database_name_inPMA > anyDbName.sql
Enter password:your_password_here
```

hit enter and your SQL file is exported into bin folder with name (anyDbName.sql)

Comment: Dont work for me...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, t**his error occurs when the mysql port is not correct**. Use this command:

`mysqldump -u root -p --port=3307 DBNAME_inPHPMYADmin > database.sql from C:\xampp\mysql\bin folder`

Make sure correct port is used. Worked for me! :)

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)" when trying to connect